# find minimum and justify it

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

After having found the derivative of [image]
which if i am not mistaken is :

[image]

I need to find the minimum of the function for which if I am not mistaken I equal to 0 the first derivative is this the right way? I am a little bit confused on how to solve this:
 [image: solve this]

Wolfram alpha doesn't seem to work :(

Thanks in advanced

Comment: You miss a $x$ in your derivative

Comment: fixed it, though I still don't know how to proceed

Comment: Should be $-\frac{1}{k}$ not $-k$ in the derivatives. Also, the third one is still missing the $x$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Derive $C(x) = 5k(202500+x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} + (1000 - x)k$:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}C}{\mathrm{d}x} = 5kx(202500)^{-\frac{1}{2}} - k$$

2. Equal the derivative to zero and solve:

$$5kx(202500 + x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}} - k = 0$$

Take the $k$ to the right side:

$$5kx(202500 + x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = k$$

Power the two sides of your equation by 2:

\begin{eqnarray}
5kx(202500 + x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}} & = & k \\
\left(5kx(202500 + x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2 & = & k^2 \\
25k^2x^2(202500 + x^2)^{-1} & = & k^2
\end{eqnarray}

Rearrange the equation to get:

$$\frac{x^2}{202500 + x^2} = \frac{k^2}{25k^2}$$

(Notice that you can cancel the two $k^2$ in the right side (assuming $k \neq 0$), well, I will carry them until the end).

You should now compute the division of the left side. Because there is no way to write it down here, I provide the result for you:

$$\frac{x^2}{202500 + x^2} = 1 - \frac{202500}{x^2 + 202500}$$

So your equation now seems like:

$$1 - \frac{202500}{x^2 + 202500} = \frac{k^2}{25k^2}$$

Take the 1 in the left to the right side and do the sum:

$$- \frac{202500}{x^2 + 202500} = \frac{k^2}{25k^2} - 1 = - \frac{24k^2}{25k^2}$$

Multiply both sides by $-1$:

$$\frac{202500}{x^2 + 202500} = \frac{24k^2}{25k^2}$$

Now it's easy to solve for $x$:

$$x^2 + 202500 = \frac{(25k^2)(202500)}{24k^2}$$

So:

$$x^2 = \frac{(25k^2)(202500)}{24k^2} - 202500 = 202500\left( \frac{25k^2}{24k^2}  -1 \right) = 202500\left( \frac{k^2}{24k^2}\right)$$

Now, assuming $k \neq 0$, the solutions are:

\begin{eqnarray}
x_1 & = & \sqrt{\frac{202500}{24}} = 75\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \\
x_2 & = & -\sqrt{\frac{202500}{24}} = -75\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}
\end{eqnarray}

In approximate form:

\begin{eqnarray}
x_1 & = & 91.8559\ldots \\
x_2 & = & -91.8559\ldots
\end{eqnarray}

3. Now, the two previous values are the critical points of $C(x)$. Now you should prove if they correspond to minimals or maximals by using the second-order derivative of $C$. Good luck!